# Using dependent: :destroy isn't working on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy, belongs-to, dependent-destroy

I have a table Bmp with these associations

```
class Bmp < ActiveRecord::Base
  #associations
     has_many :subareas, dependent: :destroy
     belongs_to :scenario
```

and another table Subareas

```
class Subarea < ActiveRecord::Base
  #associations
      belongs_to :scenarios
      belongs_to :soil
      belongs_to :bmp
```

however, when I try to delete a bmp, it should delete my subarea as well, but it is not doing so.

```
  def destroy
    @bmp = Bmp.find(params[:id])
    @bmp.destroy
```

I don't see where I've messed up, any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you confirm subarea contains value in  `bmp_id` field?

Comment: can you post a dump of your server's log when you try to destroy something

Comment: @Kumar sorry I'm really new to rails, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your subareas will still belongs to scenarios !! If you delete them associations will be broken between them  .

- Remove "belongs_to :scenarios" in subarea.rb .
- Add "has_many :subareas ,trough: :bmp" in scenario.rb .

This will maintain relations between subareas and scenarios but will put bmp "on the way " between them and will allow "chain destroy".